# If you roll a natural 1 for a skill check, is that a critical failure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, fumbles

Or do you just add your bonus like it was any other number? I'm asking because of [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112239/is-there-any-known-reason-why-trap-finding-for-mundane-traps-gets-ridiuously-eas) about traps and how easy it is to find them at mid to high level.

My first thought was that a natural 1 on a skill check would still ensure that there was at least a 5% chance on the die to miss the Pendulum of Doom hidden in the ceiling. However, I want to make sure this isn't just some kind of house rule I've been playing with forever. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

### Only if you houserule it to be.

There is no mention of auto-failing or auto-succeeding skill checks in [the *Skill Checks* section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Skill-Checks1) of the d20PFSRD.

As such, there is no RAW support for this, although it is a common houserule.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes the initial question that I saw a little more interesting...